# Problems with uploading files with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

My current code (not working):

```
<label for="homepage"><h3>Home Page Image</h3></label><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" /><input type="file" name="homepage" />
        <?php
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['homepage']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type= $_FILES['homepage']['type'];
            $name = strtolower($_POST['title']) . ".png";
            $upload_dir = "/slideshow/";
            $file_path = "$upload_dir/$name";
            list($width, $height, $type, $attr)=getimagesize("$tmp_name");

            if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $file_type == "image/png" && $width==800 && $height==250)
            {
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$upload_dir/$name");
            }
            elseif((isset($_POST['submit']) && ($file_type != "image/png" || $width!=800 || $height!=250)))
            {
                echo "<div class=\"errorcheck\">Please select an image that meets the requirements. </div>";
                echo "$width $height $type";
            }
        ?>
</br>
```

Returns "Warning: move_uploaded_file(slideshow/test.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/xxx/xxx/back_end/add.php on line 93 Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpGXQv9g' to 'slideshow/test.png' in /home/xxx/xxx/back_end/add.php on line 93"

I am a beginner to this so please explain in a simple way thanks.

Comment: Is there a `<form>` tag lurking somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have pretty much no error handling, follow the recommendations on php.net:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

To start with, for debugging at least print out the `$_FILES` array:

```
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
```

Comment: it returned: Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0)

Comment: @Callum Your HTML is wrong then, it is not submitting a file: [4 = no file](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: can you see above where I have gone wrong because I can't see anything?

Comment: @Callum no `<form>` tag for a start.

Comment: ok, you were right before, I had referenced the same name in another file upload field that was posting nothing and now I feel like an idiot. Thanks heaps though Mr. O.

Comment: Now I get the errors: Warning: move_uploaded_file(slideshow/test.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/xxx/xxx/back_end/add.php on line 93

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpGXQv9g' to 'slideshow/test.png' in /home/xxx/xxx/back_end/add.php on line 93

Comment: @Callum your destination directory does not have the correct persmissions.

Comment: @Callum directories must be executable, `777`.

Comment: well i'm trying to put it into a folder called slideshow which is at the same level as the php file is, I have tried both and neither works

Comment: You have solved my problem, sorry for wasting your time. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The problem here (I think) is the way you reference the $tmp_name variable.

It shouldn't be in double quotes. Or it should be like this

```
...getimagesize("${tmp_name}");
```

Comment: thats true, although it did not fix my problem, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there may be a lot of errors where you are trying to echo and use variable within the functions. When doing so and calling them with the $variable within the quotes, you are coding it as a set string and not a variable. For instance:

```
$foo = 'bar';
echo $foo;
Result: bar

$foo = 'bar';
echo '$foo';
Result: $foo
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
$name = strtolower($_POST['title']) . ".png";
$upload_dir = "/slideshow/";
$file_path = "$upload_dir/$name";
```

to this:

```
$file_path = $upload_dir."/".$name;
```

and

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$upload_dir/$name");
```

to this:

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $file_path);
```

when you use  tag don't forget the  tag...or else it will not submit the value for POST method.